# how to get super folder address

Tags: php, cakephp

How can I get the super folder address in cakephp?for example the current address is img/uploads/2012,and I want img/uploads.the address change dynamicly and I can't remove the /2012 from string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's magic constant **DIR** to get the directory of the current file (which is /path/to/img/uploads/2012), then go up one level:

```
$path = __DIR__ . '/..';
```

Which will point to /path/to/img/uploads/2012/.. (which points to /path/to/img/uploads)

This magic constant was only introduced in PHP 5.3 though, so for earlier versions you would use the dirname() function and the magic constant **FILE**:

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__); // returns '/path/to/img/uploads/2012'
```

Which is convenient because you can just call dirname() on the output of dirname() to go up however many levels you like:

```
$path = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)); // returns '/path/to/img/uploads'
```

Comment: it returns C:\wamp\www\imageupload\app,I want this address:img/uploads to show to user and this address:127.0.0.1/imageuploads/... for myself!

Answer (score 0):

```
//you can define the web root dir first if the framework not define:
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
//then used this code
$path = dirname(__FILE__);
$path = str_replace(ROOT . "/", "", $path);//return img/uploads
```